# SQL Server - Slowly Changing dimension join

Tags: sql-server, scd

I have a fact table and employee "tier" table, let's say.

So the fact table looks sorta like

```
employee_id    call    date
Mark           1       1-1-2017
Mark           2       1-2-2017
John           3       1-2-2017
```

Then there needs to be a data structure for 'tier level' - a slowly changing dimension table. I want to keep this simple -- I can change the structure of this table to whatever, but for now I've created it as such.

```
employee_id   tier1_start ... tier2_start ... tier3_start
Mark           5-1-2016
John           6-1-2016         8-1-2016
Lucy           6-1-2016                       10-1-2016
```

Two important notes. This table sort of operates under the assumption that a promotion will only occur once - aka no demotions and repromotions will occur. Also, it's possible one can jump from tier 1 to tier 3.

I was trying to come up with the best possible query for coming up with a 'tier' dimension (denormalization) for the fact table.

For instance, I want to see the Tier 1 metrics for February, or the Tier 2 metrics for February. Obviously the historically-changing tier dimension must be linked.

The clumsiest way I can think of doing this for now ... is simply joining the fact table on the tier table using employee_id.

Then, doing an even clumsier case statement:

```
case
when isnull(tier3_start,'0') < date then 'T3'
when isnull(tier2_start, '0') < date then 'T2'
when isnull(tier1_start, '0') < date then 'T1'
else 'other'
end as tier_level
```

Yes, as you can see this is very clumsy.
I'm thinking maybe I need to change the structure of this a bit.

Comment: Will there ever be more than 3 tiers? You've described a type 3 SCD you might be better served by a type 2 SCD (where a row is added, not a column) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension. This allows any changing attribute to be captured

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of an actual simplified, coherent query to actually join fact data with dimension data. For instance, a call was made October 3rd, or whenever. What tier does this fall under? And type 3 is not valid, it actually destroys historical effective dates. This is the problem with a lot of SCD discussions. Everyone talks about forming the dimension tables - nobody actually talks about the query that does the REAL lifting! What I really have is a type 2 SCD table. The most efficient for writing to. I need to convert that into Type 6. Most efficient for fact-table-joins.

Comment: Your dimension does not add a row per state change so it's not a type 2. Dw's simplify queries by making the ETL complicated. It seems like you already know all this though. I'm not really sure what the question is here.

Comment: An _an actual simplified, coherent query_ is to just join on your surrogate keys and your answer comes out the other side. The only thing SCD2 doesn't cover is when an employee changes state but there is no activity in the period to join to the dimension and make it appear.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off splitting your tier table in two.

So have a Tier table like this:

```
TierID    Tier
------------------
1         Tier 1
2         Tier 2
3         Tier 3
```

And an EmployeeTier table:

```
ID    EmpID    TierID    TierDate
---------------------------------------
1     1        1         Jun 1, 2016
2     1        3         Oct 2, 2016
3     2        1         Jul 10, 2016
4     2        2         Nov 11, 2016
```

Now you can query the EmployeeTier table and filter on the TierID you're looking for.

This also gives you the ability to promote/demote multiple times.  You simply filter by the employee and sort by date to find the current tier.

Comment: This is fine - but doesn't answer the fundamental problem of 'simplifying' the query. How would I join a fact table to your employeetier table? (forget the dimension table with the descriptions for the now). How would you perform the join? You can't simply have fact date > tierdate, because you would get multiple results!

Comment: What do you want to do with the query?  Something like get the number of calls per tier for the specific time period?

Comment: @user45867 - You can solve this by joining to a subquery and `ORDER`ing and `LIMIT`ing the results. If you order the results by `TierDate DESC` and limit the results to 1, you can easily join to what the latest row was at an arbitrary date.